# How to change a mesh into light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, light, eevee-render-engine

Are there any way to change a mesh completely into light? If then are there a way to give it multiple colors.

Any render engine will work

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure this is exactly what you mean but you if you want a shader only approach, try something like this. Lights in Cycles are just Emission objects anyway.

[image: Lights]

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you use **Eevee**, the object won't emit light around it unless you use a *Light Probe > Irradiance Volume*. In that case you need to put the light probe where you want the scene to be affected, tweak the settings in the light probe object data settings, and in the *Properties panel > Render > Indirect Lighting*, press on the *Bake* button. Now the object emits light around it:

[image]

Another way would be to add a light *Point* at the same location in order to fake the emission around the object, in that case make sure that the light *Radius* is large enough:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use an emission shader,

[image]

or in the Pincipled BSDF shader use the Emission color and Emission strength.

[image]

For multiple colors use a texture and plug it to the color socket of either shader.

[image]